# Find with starting index?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to figure out how to find the "next matching" object in a C# `List<MyObject>` where I have a starting index.

Meaning suppose I have the following list.

```
List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>
{
  new MyObject
  {
    isActive = true
  },
  new MyObject
  {
    isActive = false
  },
  new MyObject
  {
    isActive = true
  },
}
```

And I want to do `myList.Find(x => x.IsActive) /// where index is greater than 0??`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-findindex(system-int32-system-predicate((-0)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-findindex(system-int32-system-predicate((-0)))) method on `List`s that accepts a starting index value and a predicate so you could do something like this:

`var idx = myList.FindIndex(1, x => x.IsActive)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq` `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault` to skip the first object and get the first occurence of an object that is active or it's default value, or you can use `First` if you want an exception to be thrown if no match is found:

```
myList.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```

Comment: how would I know how many to skip? My example was a small, what if the array contains 1,000 objects and I need to skip 242?

Comment: @SlappingTheBass12 `Skip(242)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index using `FindIndex` and then retrieve the item:

```
var idx = myList.FindIndex(2, x => x.IsActive);
var item = idx >= 0 ? myList[idx] : default(MyObject);
```

As an alternative, you can use `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var item = myList
  .Skip(123)
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```